# I have a list and I want to count the occurrence of items at a certain position in my list

Tags: python, file, count, lines

I have a file which was transformed to a list. Now I want to count the occurrence of specific elements in a list at a specific position. Here is my code so far:

```
Inpu = open("I.txt","r")
entries = []
for line in Inpu:
    line=line.lstrip()
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        row = line.split()
        entries.append(row)
count0 = 0
count1 = 0
for item in entries:
    try:
        if item[3] == '1':
                count1 += 1
        if item[3] == '0':
                count0 += 1
                print item
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

This for loop statement works fine and gives me total of count1 and count0 in my file.

```
for line in Inpu:
    line=line.lstrip
    if not line.startwith('#'):
        rows=line.split() 
        peptide_count.append(row)


    for line in Inpu:
            for i in line:
                while i in line[0]=='1':
                    peptide_length+=1
                    if i in line[3] == '1':
                        count1= str(line[3]).count(1)
                        print (count1)
                        if i in line[3] == '0':
                            count0=str(item[3]).count(0) 
                            print str(count0)   
            else:
                if i in line[0]=='>':
                    break
print ("peptide_Lengths|1s|0s")
print(str(peptide_length) + "\t" + str(countones) + "\t" + str(countz))
```

This on the other hand is suppose to count the number of occurrences of zero's and ones's in line 3  when line[0] position starts with 1 and should break when it comes a cross '>' in line[0] in my file. But here is the out put I get which is obviously wrong:

```
peptide_Lengths|1s|0s
0       0       0
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or missing?

Comment: You're likely encountering an instance of the x/y problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: What about stringifying the argument of count ?